# Ado query to change colors of ticket once condition is met

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I'm working on writing a few ADO queries for tickets on our board but I'm having trouble writing them as I only have experience with JQL in JIRA.

I want a query that highlights tickets in blue when the ticket has been in the Peer Review status for 2 days. I think I need to use the Status Changed Date field in ADO but I'm having trouble with it.

I also want a condition on the board that restricts the ability to move from Ready to In-Progress if there is no Story Point assigned. I'm not sure how to implement this in ADO and the Microsoft docs are messy and hard to work with.

I tried using the Status Changes Date field to change the colours but I wasn't getting the result I expected

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your primary question regarding changing the colours of tickets on your Board, **this is done by adding a styling rule under the Board settings**. This is not done using a query, however writing the styling rules is done in a similar way.

To access the styling rules for your **Board**, navigate to the Board you are interested in, click on the settings sprocket on the top-right of the screen and then click on the 'Styles' tab in the new window that just opened. You can now add a new Styling rule by adding clauses much like a query and also choosing the styling you wish to have applied.

One important point to note here is that the rules are applied in order so the first rule that is matched will be the one that is applied. Keep this in mind when ordering your rules and when deciding how to write your rule criteria.

The Microsoft documentation on this topic is also very helpful which you can access [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/customize-cards?view=azure-devops#define-style-rules-to-highlight-cards).

One final point, I have assumed here that you are interested in styling cards on **Boards**, however it is also possible to style cards on the **Sprint Taskboard**. This is done the same way, whereby you first navigate to the **Taskboard** and then click on the settings sprocket on the top-right of the screen. From there the steps are the same.
The Microsoft documentation on Taskboard styling can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/customize-taskboard?view=azure-devops#define-style-rules-highlight-cards).